# Laravel 5 missing page and authed users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have some code in `app\ExceptionsHandler.php` that checks if a URL exists, if not then it will check the database if it is a custom URL, if so then it will return a view. The problem with this is, I think, because it is not being passed through the web middleware, none of the session and auth is being started because `Auth::id()` is null, even though I am 100% logged in

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        if(\App\EventMeter::isURL()) {
            $ec = new EventsController();
            return $ec->eventMeter();
        }
        if(\App\Tournament::isTournamentURL()) {
            $t = new TournamentController();
            return $t->home();
        }
        if(BountyHunter::isURL())
        {
            $bhc = new BountyHunterController();
            return $bhc->home();
        }

        return response()->view('errors.missing',array(), 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: I think because you instantiated the controller !! just redirect the current request like this `return redirect()->route('route.name');`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because the URL will always be dynamic. If I were to make the route a static URL then this would all work fine but the url will never stay the same

Comment: The URL to hit this method `$ec->eventMeter()` will change ??

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's something that you should shift the responsibility to your routing.

---

```
Route::get('{uri}', ['uses' => 'PageController@view', 'as' => 'page'])
      ->where('uri', '.*');
```

A Controller can handle all your views and can perform the routing and redirect, allowing you to have any other Route that you need. By creating a class, for example, a LayoutService that can handle all your different Events, Tournament, Bounty which can redirect to an appropriate location. This will let you have access to all your web middleware.

```
// Logic to determine what method you want to be called
$template = 'events|tournament|etc';

if (method_exists($this->layoutService, $template)
       && is_callable(array($this->layoutService, $template))) {
       return call_user_func(
       array($this->layoutService, $template)
    );
}
```